# What do you do when you have your kids

Tags: idiomatic-language

Person: How often do you see your kids?

Divorced father: I see them every Friday.

Person: **What do you do when you have them?**

Divorced father: We usually go to the arcades.

Is the highlighted question natural in the context? Is it natural to use ***have them*** here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is both grammatical and natural to use in this context. *Them* is also appropriate as there are multiple kids and not a single kid.

Comment: To _have a child_ can mean to give birth, but obviously it doesn't in this context. The father _has_ the children in his charge on Fridays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with Xnero. The grammar and use of the word "them" is fine in this context. In situations where divorced parents are sharing joint-custody of their children, they often ask who "has" the kids in order to plan their week.

For example:

"Frank **has the kids** on Tuesdays and Wednesdays, *and I **have them** the rest of the week."

Or

"You forgot to pick up the kids! **You have them** on weekends, remember?"